# Next.js - NextAuth always returns a positive status code

Tags: javascript, next.js, next-auth

I am using NextAuth in my Next.js project, The problem I am facing is that NextAuth is always returning a 200 status code and updates the session status to authenticated, even when the password or username do not match. I have tried throwing simple errors but none work for me.

Here is the login request I am sending:

```js
signIn("credentials", {
  email: values.email,
  password: values.password,
  redirect: false,
}).then((res) => {
  console.log(res);
  if (res.status === 200) {
    toast.update(toastId, {
      render: "Login Success ",
      type: "success",
      isLoading: false,
      autoClose: 2000,
      draggable: true,
      position: "top-right",
      closeButton: true,
    });
  }
});
```

And here the code of callback that I am using:

```js
pages: {
    signIn: "/login",
},
callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user }) {
        if (user) {
            token.accessToken = user.token;
            token.role = user.role;
        }
        return token;
    },
    
    async session({ session, token }) {
        if (token) {
            session.accessToken = token.accessToken;
            session.role = token.role;
            return session;
        }
    },
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem that you with app router:

First of all:
Dont use nextAuth with app router... Have to many issues ;)

I recommend you use with pages directory
This repository have a nice example https://github.com/steven-tey/dub

You can code all you application with app router if you want it but i recommend use the page directory to write your API :D

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).